# ASP.NET CORE AJAX request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to submit my form data, but before I wanted to check my query and get the data in the
`objOrderViewModel`
I checked with debugger, no data comes, only DateTime, what could be the problem?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult Index(OrderViewModel objOrderViewModel)
       {          
           return Json(data: "");
       }
```

My js

```
       var objOrderViewModel = {};
       var ListOrderDetailViewModel = new Array();
       objOrderViewModel.PaymentTypeId = $("#PaymentType").val();
       objOrderViewModel.CustomerId = $("#Customer").val();
       objOrderViewModel.FinalTotal = $("#txtFinalTotal").val();
       $("#tblRestaurantItemList").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
           var objOrderDetailViewModel = {};
           objOrderDetailViewModel.ItemId = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
           objOrderDetailViewModel.Quantity = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
           objOrderDetailViewModel.Total = $(this).find("td:eq(5)").text();
           objOrderDetailViewModel.Discount = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").text();
           objOrderDetailViewModel.UnitPrice = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
           ListOrderDetailViewModel.push(objOrderDetailViewModel);
       });
       objOrderViewModel.listOrderDetailViewModel = ListOrderDetailViewModel;

       $.ajax({
           async: true,
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'JSON',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           data: JSON.stringify(objOrderViewModel),
           url: '/home/Index',
           success: function (data) { alert(data) },
           error: function () { alert('There is some problem to get the unit price.') }
       });

       ResetItems();
       ResetItemsDetails();
   }
```

My Model

```
 public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
        public decimal FinalTotal { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderDetailViewModel> listOrderDetailViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check F12 Developer Tools, network tab.  That will allow you to inspect the AJAX call and payload being sent to your controller.  If you don't see your form data there, try debugging your JavaScript to make sure the object has the data you expect before you pass it to the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I forgot to put single quotes around the `__RequestVerificationToken` in the `GetToken()` function. They are there now.

This answer assumes you have `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` in your controller.

You need to submit the anti-forgery token, since it is a POST. POSTS require the anti-forgery token when validation tags are applied in the controller. In AJAX, you need to add the token manually.

At the top of your CSHTML file, add this line: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. This is your manual anti-forgery token.

You may want to make this JavaScript function for future convenience.

```
function GetToken() {
    return document.querySelector("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").value;
}
```

Add a parameter to your data that you send through AJAX. This parameter should be named `__RequestVerificationToken` and its value should be `GetToken()`, which is the value of the anti-forgery token, coming from the JavaScript function above.